# Ansible filter a list of dictionaries to only contain unique values in one field

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries in an ansible variable. Some dictionaries have the same value in the field `'id` and the field `'name'` while they differ in other key value pairs (that are not important for me). I want to filter out all those dictionaries that are "duplicates" regarding the `'name'` and `'id'` fields.

Example:

```
[{
        "name": "abc",
          "id": "123456",
   "other_key": "unimportant value"
  },
  {
        "name": "abc",
          "id": "123456",
   "other_key": "another unimportant value"
  },
  {
        "name": "bcd",
          "id": "789012",
   "other_key": "unimportant value"
  }]
```

Desired result:

```
[{
        "name": "abc",
          "id": "123456"
  },
  {
        "name": "bcd",
          "id": "789012"
  }]
```

How can I achieve this in Ansible? (the `'other_key'` variable does not necessarily have to be discarded it could also be e.g. just the first occurrence, it just does not matter).

I already produced a list of unique ids with:

```
{{ mydictionaries | map(attribute='id') | unique | list }}
```

But how do I filter the list of dictionaries with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter only the desired keys from your map list with [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) and then apply the `unique` filter.

```
{{ mydictionnaries | json_query('[].{"name": name, "id": id}') | unique }}
```

Below a proof of concept playbook. Please note in the above doc that `json_query` requires `pip install jmespath` on the ansible controller.

```
---
- name: Unique filtered dictionaries list example
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    mydictionaries: [{"name": "abc","id": "123456","other_key": "unimportant value"},{"name": "abc","id": "123456","other_key": "another unimportant value"},{"name": "bcd","id": "789012","other_key": "unimportant value"}]

  tasks:
    - name: Filter out list as wanted
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            mydictionaries
            | json_query('[].{"name": name, "id": id}')
            | unique
          }}
```

which gives

```
PLAY [Unique filtered dictionaries list example] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Filter out list as wanted] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "id": "789012",
            "name": "bcd"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! However, I had to remove the quotes within the json_query, i.e. `json_query('[].{name: name, id: id}')` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Filter out dictionaries that are "duplicates" regarding the 'name' and 'id' fields."***

Update.

A: Given the list

```yaml
  my_list:
    - {id: '123456', name: abc, other_key: unimportant value}
    - {id: '123456', name: abc, other_key: another unimportant value}
    - {id: '789012', name: bcd, other_key: unimportant value}
```

declare the variables

```yaml
  my_hash: "{{ my_list|json_query('[].[name, id]')|
                       map('join')|
                       map('hash')|
                       map('community.general.dict_kv', 'hash') }}"
  my_list2: "{{ my_list|zip(my_hash)|map('combine') }}"
  my_dict3: "{{ dict(my_list2|groupby('hash')|
                              map('last')|
                              map('first')|
                              json_query('[].[name, id]')) }}"
  my_list3: "{{ my_dict3|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='id') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  my_hash:
    - {hash: 370194ff6e0f93a7432e16cc9badd9427e8b4e13}
    - {hash: 370194ff6e0f93a7432e16cc9badd9427e8b4e13}
    - {hash: f3814d5b43a4d67d7636ec64be828d82a92eedbb}

  my_list2:
  - hash: 370194ff6e0f93a7432e16cc9badd9427e8b4e13
    id: '123456'
    name: abc
    other_key: unimportant value
  - hash: 370194ff6e0f93a7432e16cc9badd9427e8b4e13
    id: '123456'
    name: abc
    other_key: another unimportant value
  - hash: f3814d5b43a4d67d7636ec64be828d82a92eedbb
    id: '789012'
    name: bcd
    other_key: unimportant value

  my_dict3:
    abc: '123456'
    bcd: '789012'

  my_list3:
    - {id: '123456', name: abc}
    - {id: '789012', name: bcd}
```

Optionally, convert *id* from string to number

```yaml
  my_dict3: "{{ dict(my_list2|groupby('hash')|
                              map('last')|
                              map('first')|
                              json_query('[].[name, to_number(id)]')) }}"
  my_list3: "{{ my_dict3|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='id') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  my_dict3:
    abc: 123456
    bcd: 789012

  my_list3:
    - {id: 123456, name: abc}
    - {id: 789012, name: bcd}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_list:
      - {id: '123456', name: abc, other_key: unimportant value}
      - {id: '123456', name: abc, other_key: another unimportant value}
      - {id: '789012', name: bcd, other_key: unimportant value}

    my_hash: "{{ my_list|json_query('[].[name, id]')|
                         map('join')|
                         map('hash')|
                         map('community.general.dict_kv', 'hash') }}"
    my_list2: "{{ my_list|zip(my_hash)|map('combine') }}"
    my_dict3: "{{ dict(my_list2|groupby('hash')|
                                map('last')|
                                map('first')|
                                json_query('[].[name, to_number(id)]')) }}"
                              # json_query('[].[name, id]')) }}"
    my_list3: "{{ my_dict3|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='id') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_list|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_hash|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_list2
    - debug:
        var: my_dict3
    - debug:
        var: my_list3|to_yaml
```

---

Origin.

Given the data is stored in the variable `my_list`, let's add the `hash` attribute, created from the `name` and `id` attributes, to the list. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list2: "{{ my_list2|default([]) +
                      [item|combine({'hash': (item.name ~ item.id)|hash})] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list2
```

give

```yaml
  my_list2:
  - hash: 370194ff6e0f93a7432e16cc9badd9427e8b4e13
    id: '123456'
    name: abc
    other_key: unimportant value
  - hash: 370194ff6e0f93a7432e16cc9badd9427e8b4e13
    id: '123456'
    name: abc
    other_key: another unimportant value
  - hash: f3814d5b43a4d67d7636ec64be828d82a92eedbb
    id: '789012'
    name: bcd
    other_key: unimportant value
```

Subsequent use [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#groupby) filter and select the required attributes. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list3: "{{ my_list3|default([]) +
                      [{'name': item.1.0.name, 'id': item.1.0.id}] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list2|groupby('hash') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list3
```

give

```yaml
  my_list3:
    - {id: '123456', name: abc}
    - {id: '789012', name: bcd}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_list:
      - {id: '123456', name: abc, other_key: unimportant value}
      - {id: '123456', name: abc, other_key: another unimportant value}
      - {id: '789012', name: bcd, other_key: unimportant value}

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_list2: "{{ my_list2|default([]) +
                      [item|combine({'hash': (item.name ~ item.id)|hash})] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list2

    - set_fact:
        my_list3: "{{ my_list3|default([]) +
                      [{'name': item.1.0.name, 'id': item.1.0.id}] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list2|groupby('hash') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list3|to_yaml
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well, too. I chose Zeitounator's solution for my current problem, as that one does it all in one step (less code). However, your solution has the advantage that it works also without the jmespath dependency on the ansible controller, which will be certainly handy in many situations.

Comment: Sure. This one is more complex. In addition to this, it is able to sort by any combination of the keys (e.g. id[0:2]).